# How to check if java.lang.reflect.Type is an Enum

Tags: java, class, reflection, types, enums

I want to check whether a `java.lang.reflect.Type` instance represents an Emum object or not.

I can check whether it's an instance of a specific class using == comparisons e.g:

```
type == String.class // works
```

but this doesn't seem to work for the Enum class:

```
type == Enum.class // doesn't work
```

... this makes sense as the instance would be of a specific enum but I would like to check whether the type is for any enum or not.

Could someone explain the obvious to me of how to tell whether the Type is an enum or not please

Comment: what's wrong with Class.isEnum()?

Comment: I'm using Type object as it supports primitive types. I'd like to be able to call isEnum() but it's not on the Type object

Comment: failed to understand your comment. Class implements Type.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
if(type instanceof Class && ((Class<?>)type).isEnum())
```

Comment: Thanks, i knew it would be something obvious

Answer (score 13):

Class.isEnum() will do it for you.

Refer to [Oracle Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isEnum%28%29)

Comment: could you be more specific please on how to implement this

Comment: it would translate to `type.isEnum()` from your example.

Comment: I like this answer, and think it's less confusing than the one above

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use .equals method to compare this type of comparisons. == is mostly used for primitive types.

```
type.equals(Enum.class)
```

or maybe you will need compare your own classes.

```
type.equals(MyClass.class)
```

Comment: I think you second suggestion would work but I need it to work with any enum... not just those explicitly defined

Answer (score 0):

```
if(type instanceof Class && (Class)type.getClass().isEnum()) {...}
```

Comment: type.getClass() returns 'class' and not my enum

Comment: ah yes... I'm afraid @jtahlborn suggested this already. Thanks for your efforts though